# Android SurfaceView with drawBitmap(Matrix) leaves blinking ghost image

Tags: android, graphics, 2d

To preface, I'm probably going to work with Views instead of SurfaceView given this weird interaction, but my curiosity is getting the better of me and I want to know what's going on.

So I have a matrix class variable. I run matrix.setTranslate() once, and every other frame I say matrix.setTranslate(). After this I call canvas.drawBitmap(, matrix, null). After 100 frames, I stop drawing the bitmap.

Here's the code:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //      matrix = new Matrix(); //Doesn't matter if I add this.
    //      matrix.reset(); //This doesn't matter either.
    if (!once) {
        matrix.setTranslate(100, 100);
    } else {
        matrix.setTranslate(800,800);
    }
    once = true;
    if (++timer < 100) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball, matrix, null);
    }
}
```

**What I expect to happen:** Three possibilities.

1. Only the bottom right bitmap is visible since the entire screen was invalidated
2. Both bitmaps are visible because SurfaceView was smart with the dirty rectangle
3. Nothing is shown because nothing was drawn.

**What actually happens: *The top left bitmap blinks, bottom right bitmap displays solidly.***

I'm pretty sure I have all of my bases covered:

- All class variables are properly set in the constructor.
- SurfaceView.onDraw() is called every 33 millis in its own thread.
- Thread calls lockCanvas, then onDraw, then unlockCanvasAndPost

So, what's going on here? And bonus question, do these ghost images consume any extra resources and how can I clear them?

Rest of the code, mostly boilerplate:

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    GameSurface ball;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ball = new GameSurface(this);
        setContentView(ball);
    }
}


class GameSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    GameThread thread;
    boolean once = false;
    Bitmap ball;
    Matrix matrix;
    int timer = 0;


    public GameSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.football);
        matrix = new Matrix();

        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

//      matrix = new Matrix(); //Doesn't matter if I add this.
//      matrix.reset(); //This doesn't matter either.
        if (!once) {
            matrix.setTranslate(100, 100);
        } else {
            matrix.setTranslate(800,800);
        }
        //matrix.postRotate(timer); //For even more weirdness...
        once = true;
        if (++timer < 100) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(ball, matrix, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }


    class GameThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private GameSurface gameView;
        private boolean run = false;

        public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GameSurface gameView) {
            this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            this.gameView = gameView;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            this.run = run;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas c;
            while (run) {
                c = null;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(33);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e) {}

                try {
                    c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                        gameView.onDraw(c);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```